# (Math.random()*x)+y returns numbers greater than x+y

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

So I've been using HTML canvas and Javascript to create random images. Most of it is running pretty smoothly, but recently I've been encountering problems.

I am trying to add a user interface where users can create upper and lower bounds for the red, green and blue values of the pixels, as well as change the size of the pixels. The colors are giving me trouble.

For some reason, the following function:

```
function getRandomInt(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

is returning values greater than max. I haven't quite been able to figure out why yet.

For more information, @max and @min are sourced from `<input type="number">` tags with code like:

```
rmax = document.getElementById('rmax').value;
```

in another function.

Then, they are stored in an array of arrays of arrays (I know that is messy memory wise, but the array size should never be horribly large so it's not a problem for that reason currently.).

IE:

```
var height = canv.getAttribute("height");
var width = canv.getAttribute("width");
var tall = Math.floor(height/blockh)+1;
var wide = Math.floor(width/blockw)+1;
var mat = new Array(wide);
for(var i = 0; i<wide; i++){
    mat[i] = new Array(tall);
}
for(var i = 0; i<wide; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<tall; j++){
        r = getRandomInt(rmin,rmax);
        g = getRandomInt(gmin,gmax);
        b = getRandomInt(bmin,bmax);
        mat[i][j] = new Array(4);
        mat[i][j][0] = r;
        mat[i][j][1] = g;
        mat[i][j][2] = b;
        mat[i][j][3] = false;
    }
}
```

Finally, I run through `mat` and draw each pixel using canvas:

```
for(var i = 0; i<wide; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<tall; j++){
        drawBlock(ctx,mat[i][j][0],mat[i][j][1],mat[i][j][2],(i*blockw),(j*blockh));
        mat[i][j][3] = true;
    }
}
//more code
function drawBlock(canv,r,g,b,x,y) {
  color = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+"1)";
  canv.beginPath();
  canv.fillStyle=color;
  canv.moveTo(x,y);
  canv.lineTo(x+blockw,y);
  canv.lineTo(x+blockw,y+blockh);
  canv.lineTo(x,y+blockh);
  canv.lineTo(x,y);
  canv.fill();
  canv.closePath();
}
```

By the nature of the `<input>` tags, all of the mins and maxes are forced between 0 and 256.

However, when I run the code, it gets the right values for the mins and maxes, but it calculates color values which go far beyond the max value. For instance, with rmin=0; and rmax=256; I have gotten r values at around 8,000. Obviously, this is a problem, as I am looking only for values between 0 and 256.

Note: When I just do the drawing based on defaults in the .js file, it works fine. I only get problems AFTER retrieving values from the `<input>` tags and then running again.

I believe the problem is in the `getRandomInt()` function, but it is possible it is in my retrieving of values from the `<input>` tags. I doubt this however, as I have done some troubleshooting and the values it retrieves appear to be correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: max and min are parameters and are not always the same, so I did not include a single value for them. Here is an example from a sample run: min=1, max=31, generated=171. I'll edit the post to include a couple examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you're passing strings as arguments.

```
getRandomInt('0', '256') // 1540
```

What happens next - is the number returned by `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))` expression is **concatenated** with the `min` *string*.

You must convert it explicitly to integers using `parseInt(rmax, 10)`

Comment: Or just `Number(rmax)` or `+rmax`.

Comment: That sounds like it would be right -- but I think the `<input type="number">` tag in HTML5 has a value of an integer, not a string. I may be wrong though. I'll try your solution.

Comment: @user3739472: use `typeof` and know it for sure.